# iText 1.3.1 : how to use a custom image as a com.lowagie.text.Image

Tags: java, image, struts, itext

I am facing an image conversion problem with iText 1.3.1 (I know it is an old version but I don't have the choice)

After a few search over forums I saw different ways of putting custom image (`.png` for example) as an iText image (`com.lowagie.text.Image`).

I tried many ways such as :

```
File imgRed = new File("smileyRed.png");
java.awt.Image smileyRed = ImageIO.read(imgRed);
com.lowagie.text.Image mySmileyRed = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(smileyRed);
```

Or :

```
URL imageUrlRed = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("smileyRed.png");
com.lowagie.text.Image mySmileyRed = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(imageUrlRed);
```

But both of these ways throw Exception (an `IOException` for the first one, and a `NullPointerException` for the second one).

Do you have an idea how could I define my image for it to work ?

The Java EE application I am working is using Struts. Maybe I could define a bean with this image if it sounds easier. How could I do that?

Comment: I forgot to add that I need this Image to add it into a Cell of a Table : I would like to display a table with Images

Comment: Have you tried `com.lowagie.text.Image mySmileyRed = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance("smileyRed.png");`? What is the stacktrace when you get the `IOException`? Could it just be an issue with the path to the image?

Comment: Yeah sorry I made a mistake in my first Exception. Here it what It says : java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\xxxxx\softs\apache-tomcat-5.5.27\smileyRed.png It can'tfind the file cause it is looking for it into Tomcat and not in my Java project...

Comment: Have you tried running your app outside the application server first?

Comment: Here is what I get when I run it outside the app server : Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\xxxxx\mtm\sources\web\service\smileyRed.png

Comment: Well, here you are : either the path/file doesn't exist, or the rights are not properly set so that your app can access it. Have you tried using the absolute path instead of the relative path?